# How to store long string in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am struggling with a little issue that I have a long string (containing an  image) having almost 8000 characters. I need to store it in SQL server and want to get back the same by using select query. Please anyone help. The string is below.

```
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
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried to store this string in database (`varbinary(MAX)` datatype) by using the following code:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_client", Convert.FromBase64String(enad.photograph));
```

This stores the data in the database successfully, but when I extract it from the database and convert it back to its original string it gives me an error.

I use below code which converts back to its orignal string:

```
byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(dt.Rows[0]["image_client"].ToString());
```

The above code generates the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: *i have a long string(contain image) having almost 8000 characters* You could just ... not store images as strings. `VARBINARY` or better yet, not in the database. Otherwise `VARBINARY(MAX)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

Comment: As long as this is image, you can go with other data types such as `blob`, `filestream`, `varbinary(max)` etc

Comment: I have followed the same as you describe. Please see my code in EDIT, thanks.

Comment: it seems that you use `Convert.FromBase64String` both time when you want to convert it to base64 and when you want to decode it! use `ToBase64String` when you want to save it in database

Comment: OK. I have successfully added using VARCHAR(max) datatype( the same string that i mentioned in my orignal thread). Here my question is that, is it a good idea to first store this string into database (not as image) and then convert back into image when needed? Is there may be any problem in future using this method?, thanks.

Comment: ntext type is your other options.

Comment: @ahankendi ntext is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @ThomasSchremser then you find your answer.

ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading `varbinary` values *from* SQL Server into a `DataTable` (assuming you use `DataAdapter` and not `DataReader`) then the value will be a `SqlBinary` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary(v=vs.110).aspx

You can get a `Byte[]` out of it via the `Value` member:

```
SqlBinary bin = (SqlBinary)dt.Rows[0]["image_client"];
Byte[] data = bin.Value;
```